# Bootstrap buttons for DataTables

Tags: datatables, visibility

Im In need of assistance when it comes to implementing [Bootstrap buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp) in a DataTable where the purpose is to toggle the columns with these buttons.

[This is how it looks like by default](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnsToggle.html) in the DataTables design, what I am trying to do is to use the Bootstrap design instead and also place the buttons to the left of the table which seem rather impossible...

If you have any suggestions please feel free to discuss it!

Comment: What did you try so far? Is there any specific part that you're stuck on? Did you check out the DataTables docs on Bootstrap? https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

Comment: My current setup has the standard toggle buttons, but I can't get bootstrap buttons to work properly aswell as get them positioned left of the table. I have read the documentation, I have not seen any example on the web where the buttons are on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Check This

Bootstrap 3
This example shows DataTables and the Buttons extension being used with the Bootstrap framework providing the styling. The DataTables / Bootstrap integration provides seamless integration for DataTables to be used in a Bootstrap page.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have experimented with this but the issue with this solution is that people can't seem to be able to place the buttons on the left side of the table, instead of on top.

Comment: Just use CSS rules to float them next to each other? The table is float right and the buttons are float left, remove any `clear: both;` that might be on the Table.

Comment: @Crysolt, an example of how to attach the buttons to a different container is also in the link.